# javascript arrays and JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm working on [Bootstrap calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar) and I've tried to make my array looks like this:

```
{
"success": 1,
"result": [
    {
        "id": "293",
        "title": "This is warning class event with very long title to check how it fits to evet in day view",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/",
        "class": "event-warning",
        "start": "1362938400000",
        "end":   "1363197686300"
    },
    {
        "id": "256",
        "title": "Event that ends on timeline",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/",
        "class": "event-warning",
        "start": "1363155300000",
        "end":   "1363227600000"
    },
    {
        "id": "276",
        "title": "Short day event",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/",
        "class": "event-success",
        "start": "1363245600000",
        "end":   "1363252200000"
    },
    {
        "id": "294",
        "title": "This is information class ",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/",
        "class": "event-info",
        "start": "1363111200000",
        "end":   "1363284086400"
    }
] }
```

But I've tried and got something like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "success":1
   },
   {  
      "result":[  
         {  
            "id":"1",
            "title":"dev",
            "url":"www.example.com",
            "class":"event-success",
            "start":"0",
            "end":"0"
         },
         {  
            "id":"2",
            "title":"Holiday",
            "url":"www.example.com",
            "class":"event-success",
            "start":"0",
            "end":"0"
         },
         {  
            "id":"3",
            "title":"Coding...",
            "url":"www.example.com",
            "class":"event-success",
            "start":"0",
            "end":"0"
         },
         {  
            "id":"4",
            "title":"data",
            "url":"www.example.com",
            "class":"event-success",
            "start":"0",
            "end":"0"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and my code to create those mess are

```
      var result = [];
  for(i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    var result_single = {id:rows[i].uid, title:rows[i].name, url:"www.example.com", class:"event-success", start:rows[i].startdate, end:rows[i].enddate};
    result.push(result_single);
  }
  var output = new Array();
  output.push(data);
  result = {result:result};
  output.push(result);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

To be honest, I don't quite understand how array in js works. can somebody point out how did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected result is an object which contains 2 properties, but you get an array which contains two objects. I think you want the first result which is object with two properties.

```js
var result = [];
var rows = [1,2,3,4,5];

for(i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    var result_single = {id:rows[i], title:rows[i], url:"www.example.com", class:"event-success",                                 start:rows[i].startdate, end:rows[i].enddate};
    result.push(result_single);
}
    
var output = {
   success: 1,
   result: result
}
      
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```